# Using tiny font with the (sub)caption package

Tags: captions, fontsize, subcaption

In some situations (e.g. with `beamer`), it may be desirable to use `tiny` as font size with the (sub)caption package. How to use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the `tiny` option is not available per default, it can easily be added using `\DeclareCaptionFont{tiny}{\tiny}`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption} 
\DeclareCaptionFont{tiny}{\tiny} 
\captionsetup{font+=tiny} 
\captionsetup[sub]{font+=tiny} 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}
        \centering  
        \subcaptionbox{Original}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}
        \subcaptionbox{New}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}
        \caption{Image}
    \end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

**EDIT May 2018:**

This workaround is no longer necessary, it was fixed in the caption package with the commit https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/8088ac29f196076ab4b9a942f96d557a36cdec47